# Python project structure error while importing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started coding in python and I encountered some errors. My text editor `(vscode)` doesn't show any error while importing the module but whenever I run the code I have encountered it.

So basically, my directory tree looks like this

```
lib/
|
|-- core/
|    |-- module.py 
|    |-- __init__.py
|    
|         
|-- python/
    |-- server.py
    |-- worker.py
    |-- __init__.py
```

When I import `module.py` from `python/server.py` and use

```py
import lib.core.module
```

I got an error: `No module name lib.core`. I tried adding "." but it doesn't work

Comment: What is the output if you insert `import os, sys; print(os.getcwd(), sys.path)` at the top of `server.py`, before the import statements?

Comment: [ 'c:\users\user\test', (python path) ]

Comment: Are any of those where `lib` is located or `lib` itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from .lib.core.module import *
```

Comment: I still get an error `No module name 'lib.core.module'`

Comment: Try it again with the dot in the front @TheodoreEscalante